# Python import and module scoping (specifically sys.ps1)

Tags: python

Why does the following not work:

```
from sys import ps1
ps1 = 'something else '
```

but this does?

```
import sys
sys.ps1 = 'something else '
```

If I run the simple test

```
import sys
from sys import ps1
ps1 = 'something else'
sys.ps1 = 'something else'
```

the first assignment doesn't work, but the second does. the id() for both ps1 and sys.ps1 are the same, so they should refer to the same thing, right?

Comment: @KevinLondon: No, it should not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version is: Assignment doesn't mutate anything in Python, it just rebinds names. Rebinding a different name, that happens to be currently bound to a reference to the same string as `sys.ps1` doesn't affect `sys.ps1` in any way.

Let's go through step by step:

```
from sys import ps1
```

This imports `sys` (but doesn't bind a name `sys` in the current globals), then binds the name `ps1` in the current globals to the same object as `sys`'s `ps1`.

```
ps1 = 'something else '
```

This rebinds the name `ps1` in the current globals to the same object as the literal `'something else'`. There's no way that could possibly affect the `sys` module.

```
import sys
```

This imports `sys`, and then binds the name `sys` in the current globals to it.

```
sys.ps1 = 'something else '
```

This looks up the name `sys` in the current globals, getting a reference to the `sys` module, then rebinds the name `ps1` in that module to the same object as the literal `'something else '`.

---

Or, putting it in pseudo-Python terms, instead of in English…

Your first code sample is like this:

```
tempspace._sys = __import__('sys')
globals.ps1 = tempspace._sys.ps1
del tempspace._sys
globals.ps1 = 'something else '
```

Your second is like this:

```
globals.sys = sys_modules.sys = __import__('sys')
globals.sys.ps1 = 'something else '
```

---

Here is a transcript of what you described in the comments.

```
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> from sys import ps1
>>> id(sys.ps1)
4360831168
>>> id(ps1)
4360831168
>>> sys.ps1 = 'something else '
something else ps1
'>>> '
something else
```

`sys.ps1` and `ps1` have the same ID, because they are two different names that reference the same object.

And changing `sys.ps1` does not change `ps1`.

Comment: If it was binding ps1 to a copy of sys.ps1, wouldn't they have different IDs? Also, once I change sys.ps1, ps1 also changes.

Comment: @victor: Yes, if you bind to a copy they have different IDs, but if you bind to the same object, it's the same object, so of course it has the same ID. And when you change `sys.ps1`, `ps1` does _not_ change. Let me edit the answer to show you.

Comment: Ah hah. I guess I was actually confused about the flip side, which is also interesting. If you replace `sys.ps1 = 'something else '` with `ps1 = 'something else '`, then `ps1` changes its ID.

Comment: @victor: Well, yes, because `ps1` now has the ID of the literal `'something else '`. The key point here is that `ps1` is just a name, and names don't have IDs; it's _values_ that have IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of confusion that Python's import statement causes should keep its inventors up at night!

Here is a page that attempts to [explain import](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm).  In particular it describes:

- **import X** imports the module X and you use *X.name* to refer to *name* defined in module X
- **from X import *** imports the module X but creates references in the
  current namespace to all public objects defined in X. You use *name* to refer to *name* that's defined in X, but X itself is not defined, so *X.name* does not work.

One way, perhaps, to look at **from X import *** is almost as if it inserts the entire source of module X inline and hence you simply use *name* directly as if it were inline and you cannot use X because it no longer exists.

Note that the practice of importing * from a module or package is [frowned upon](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).

Comment: For one thing, the OP didn't do `from X import *`, he did `from X import Y`. For another, this isn't the part he didn't understand. He already knew why he couldn't do `sys.ps1` after `from sys import ps1`, but didn't understand why changing `ps1` after a `from sys import ps1` didn't affect `sys`.

Comment: You're right, my mistake.  I have an itchy trigger finger when it comes to Python imports ;-)